# How to (dis)prove "If $f(x+n)$, where $n>0$, then graph of $f(x)$ will move to the left by $n$ units"?

Tags: functions

What I want to prove or disprove:

> If $f(x+n)$, where $n$ is any positive number, then graph of function $f(x)$
>   will move to the left by n units.

Note that if argument $x$ occurs in given function several times, then we must make the addition to each occurrence in order to get a correct result. For example, if we have $y=x^2+x$, in order to apply the transformation we must write it down as $y = (x+n)^2 + (x+n)$.

Example: (The original function is $y = x^2$, its color is red. The new function is $y = (x+2)^2$, its color is black): 
[image]
If I understand everything right, said transformation must always work for all possible one-argument functions (well, at the least my textbook seems to imply it). I tested this transformation on some functions that I know and it seems to work just fine, but I don't understand why it must be the case. This is **not** self-evident for me and I have no a clue how to either prove or disprove it. I want to see (dis)proof in order to understand why it works.
Counterexamples as a disproof are OK.

P.S. I'm aware that said transformation will "fail" (i.e. graph of given function won't change) in the case of a periodic function when n is equal to the period of said periodic function. I don't count it as a counterexample against the rule because it can be just an optical illusion if we marked any arbitrary point on said graph before the transformation we would see that it (point) moved with the rest of the graph.

Comment: If what? "If $f(x+n)$" no verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send $x \rightarrow x+2$ this means "relative to my original function, as I travel from left to right I'm hitting zero 2 units earlier." All $x$s are 2 bigger. Is this moving the function, or moving the axes? I leave that distinction in your hands. If you stare at 0, and insist it is always 0, then you moved the graph. If you stare at the graph, and insist it is always the graph, then you moved the axes.

If you're not familiar with linear algebra, please ignore this paragraph as I don't think it would be illuminating. There is a sense in which this is the same function and it's the axes that have changed, since polynomials are linear in their coefficients and this kind of translation (and others) are linear transformations of the coefficients as vectors in a space of $1,~ x,~ \ldots$, so what we're asking is what someone would think the equation of this polynomial is under a different set of basis vectors.